# Indy TCP Server - Handle OnDisconnect already deleted?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a Delphi application with a Indy TCPServer and TCPClient. I use the `AContext.Bindind.Handle` for the identification of each connection (wrong?).

So I have a grid which displayed the connections and I will remove the entry after disconnection:

```
procedure TfrmMain.serverIndyDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var I:Integer;
begin
for I := 0 to gridClients.RowCount - 1 do
begin
  if gridClients.Cells[0, I] = IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Handle) then
  begin
     gridClients.Rows[I].Delete(I);
  end;
end;

WriteLogEntry('Connection closed... (' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP+')');
end;
```

But in the Disconnect Event, the Handle is already empty (it's ever 401xxxxx, so the last Integer number).

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not mention which version of Delphi or Indy you are using, but the following holds for D2010 and Indy 10.x.

I've used the "AContext.Data" property for identification of the client. I usually Create an object there and release it when the disconnect event happens.

New OnConnect() code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.serverIndyConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Data := TMyObject.Create(NIL);
  // Other Init code goes here, including adding the connection to the grid
end;
```

Modified OnDisconnect() code below:

```
procedure TfrmMain.serverIndyDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var I:Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to gridClients.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    if gridClients.Cells[0, I] = IntToStr(AContext.Data) then
    begin
      gridClients.Rows[I].Delete(I);
    end;
 end;
 WriteLogEntry('Connection closed... (' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP+')');
end;
```

Comment: Good advice.  Always use your own identifers, do not use Indy's internal objects and handles as IDs.